# OpenGL draw spiral

Tags: c++, opengl, draw

The following code will create a new circle on openGL but how can I make it draw spiral instead of the circle?

```
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (float angle = 0; angle < 360; angle += 1)
    {
        x = 50 * cos(angle);
        y = 50 * sin(angle);
        glVertex2f(x, y);
    }
    glEnd();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the radius in the loop. e.g.:

```cpp
float radius = 0.0f;

glBegin(GL_POINTS);
for (float angle = 0; angle < 1440; angle += 1)
{
    x = cos(angle * M_PI / 180) * radius;
    y = sin(angle * M_PI / 180) * radius;
    radius += 0.1f;
    glVertex2f(x, y);
}
glEnd();
```

Note the unit of the angle of `sin` and `cos` is [Radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian).